# Html markup vertical tabs with transparent background

Tags: html, css, tabs

I'm trying to markup tabs as shown on scheme

[image]

```
.tab.active {
position: relative;
background-image: url(http://tirabit.flywebstudio.ru/images/black30.png);
color: #f99734;

}
.tab:hover {
background-image: url(http://tirabit.flywebstudio.ru/images/black20.png);
}
.tab.active:hover {
background-image: url(http://tirabit.flywebstudio.ru/images/black30.png);
}
```

Current version: http://jsfiddle.net/GrGD9/2/

But i can't understand, how to do so that active tab doesn't have right border.

Comment: I think this isn't possible without using jQuery or something. You can find a tutorial [here](http://www.faridesign.net/2012/05/create-a-awesome-vertical-tabbed-content-area-using-css3-jquery/)

Answer (score -1):

You can add border-right:0; and it will take it off!

another way is to do:
Border: 1px 1px 1px 0px;

Comment: if i set border-right: 0; then i'll see the border of content, because they all have border